# Not Able to upload .app file on testrigor

Tags: ios, .app, testrigor

We wanted to test the iOS app using TestRigor, so when we created a Testsuite and uploaded the .app file, it gave us errors
"Info.plist file wasn't found in zip archive. Please make sure that uploaded zip archive contains .app iOS application"

I have created the .app file for Release and also added Info.plist in the folder, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

The file uploaded on the Test Suite setup should be compiled for iOS Simulator (i386 or x86_64) for iOS 14.4 or older in file.app.zip format.

Here is a link related [https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/65272][1]  The build should be in xcode files: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[UDID]

After you get the build it needs to be zipped. In case the name doesn't match, it will need .app being added at the end

Comment: Thanks @Paolo But now we get the .app file from /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[appID]/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator The file pat is correct as per Xcode 13 and above  but I still get the errors here when using with TestRigor

Comment: Few useful links that can help you with this

https://testrigor.com/blog/how-to-compile-an-ios-app-for-simulator/

https://testrigor.com/blog/how-to-generate-a-file-for-testrigor-ios-simulators/